# Upper bound for the torsion subgroup of an elliptic curve over arbitrary number fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $d$ and let $E(K)$ be an elliptic curve over the field $K$ with coefficients in $K$. Let us fix $d$ and vary over all the possible $K$, in turn varying over all possible $E$. My question is the following: does there exist an integer $N=N_d$ such that $N \geq \#|E(K_{\mathrm{tors}})|$ for any $K, E$ and fixed $d$? If this is not known to be the case, then what is the general consensus regarding the number of $K$-rational torsion points of $E$? If none of this is known, is there a record for the largest known torsion order? As of right now I'm curious for $d=2$ and non-CM elliptic curves $E(K)$, but any information regarding a specific $d > 1$ is helpful.

Comment: Yes, such N exists for each d; Loïc Merel proved this (with an explicit albeit large N) in a paper published by *Inventiones mathematicæ* in 1996.  For $d=2$ The problem is completely solved. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_conjecture

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Your comment should be an answer (so that this question can be closed).

Comment: What does "over the field $K$ with coefficients in $K$" mean? I know what "over the field $K$" means (i.e. the curve is defined over $K$ and the basepoint is a $K$-point) — I would rather have written "an elliptic curve $E$ over the field $K$", with $E(K)$ rather denoting the group of $K$-points.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Thanks, this is a great answer. This question should be closed now.

Comment: @GHfromMO I didn't yet formulate my comment as an answer because I wanted to first look up the list for $d=2$ and to credit it properly.